Convert numerals from English to Arabic (Hindi) in Microsoft Office Online
This is for MS office online, can anyone help and advise how to display the numbers in Arabic (Hindi) instead of English? this is within the word-online, there is no option to change language settings in the online version.
Even if I create a document in the desired language, once I save it to onedrive and open it online (this was tested on Google Chrome, and Edge), it displays in English.
This is for MS Server 2022.
The main target is to use this within MS SharePoint system, so Word will be within the browser, and there is no local office installed on the server and the desktop.
Help is appreciated

Check the Document Language Settings
While Word Online doesn’t offer comprehensive language settings, you can still set the document's language to Arabic before uploading it. Sometimes, setting the language and regional formatting in the desktop version can help retain the number formatting once it's uploaded to OneDrive—though keep in mind, this may not work reliably in Word Online.
Adjust Browser Locale Settings
Another option is to change your browser’s locale settings to Arabic. In both Google Chrome and Edge, you can add Arabic as a preferred language. This may influence how some content, including numbers, is displayed in Office Online.
Try Embedding Fonts or Using Field Codes
If you’re preparing the document offline, you could experiment with embedding fonts or using field codes to display numbers in Arabic (Hindi). Be aware, though, that these methods might not carry over consistently when you open the document in Word Online.
Reach Out to Microsoft Support
Since this limitation is a known issue with Word Online, contacting Microsoft Support could be helpful. They may have specific solutions or SharePoint add-ons that can enable better customization in your setup.

Thanks for your efforts, I actually tried what you have suggested, with the setting, and browsers' settings, nothing worked. My next plan is to reinstall Office Online Server and configure it with Arabic, I will see what happens. Thanks again.
